# RPG em turnos - Personagem e inimigo recebem o mesmo ataque

Tags: java

Eu estou desenvolvendo um RPG em turnos e estou tendo problemas. O jogador e o inimigo são a mesma classe de objeto instanciada e eles possuem os métodos de atacar e receber dano. Contudo quando eu ataco ambos os personagens tem a vida subtraída.

> Classe Atributos

```
class Atributos 
{
    //ATRIBUTOS DA CLASSE

    public int vitalidade;
    public int armadura; 
    public int forca; 
    public int inteligencia; 
    public int agilidade; 
    public int sorte; 

    //CONSTRUTORES 

    public Atributos ()
    {
        this.vitalidade = 0; 
        this.armadura = 0; 
        this.forca = 0; 
        this.inteligencia = 0; 
        this.agilidade = 0; 
        this.sorte = 0; 
    }

    //SETTERS

    public void setVitalidade (int vitalidade)
    {
        this.vitalidade = vitalidade;
    }

    public void setArmadura (int armadura)
    {
        this.armadura = armadura;
    }

    public void setForca (int forca)
    {
        this.forca = forca; 
    }

    public void setInteligencia (int inteligencia)
    {
        this.inteligencia = inteligencia;
    }

    public void setAgilidade (int agilidade)
    {
        this.agilidade = agilidade;
    }

    public void setSorte (int sorte)
    {
        this.sorte = sorte; 
    }


    //GETTERS 

    public int getVitalidade ()
    {
        return this.vitalidade;
    }

    public int getArmadura ()
    {
        return this.armadura;
    }

    public int getForca ()
    {
        return this.forca; 
    }

    public int getInteligencia ()
    {
        return this.inteligencia;
    }

    public int getAgilidade ()
    {
        return this.agilidade;
    }

    public int getSorte ()
    {
        return this.sorte; 
    }

}
```

> Classe Personagem

```
import java.util.Random;

class Personagem extends Atributos
{

    //ATRIBUTOS

    public static String nome;
    public static String classe; 
    public static int defesa;
    public static int critico;
    public static int danoMinimo; 
    public static int danoMaximo; 
    public static int healthPoints;
    public static int manaPoints; 

    //CONSTRUTOR

    public Personagem ()
    {
        this.nome = ""; 
        this.classe = "Mago"; 
        this.vitalidade = 10;
        this.armadura = 10; 
        this.forca = 10;
        this.inteligencia = 10;
        this.agilidade = 10; 
        this.sorte = 10; 
        this.defesa = 10 + this.armadura; 
        this.critico = this.sorte / 100; 
        this.healthPoints = 100;
        this.manaPoints = 100; 
        this.danoMinimo = 10;
        this.danoMaximo = 20; 
    }

    //SETTERS 

    public void setNome (String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setClasse (String classe)
    {
        this.classe = classe;
    }

    public void setDefesa (int defesa)
    {
        this.defesa = defesa;
    }

    public void setCritico (int critico)
    {
        this.critico = critico; 
    }

    public void setHealthPoints (int healthPoints)
    {
        this.healthPoints = healthPoints;
    }

    public void setManaPoints (int manaPoints)
    {
        this.manaPoints = manaPoints;
    }

    public void setDanoMinimo (int danoMinimo)
    {
        this.danoMinimo = danoMinimo;
    }

    public void setDanoMaximo (int danoMaximo)
    {
        this.danoMaximo = danoMaximo; 
    }

    //GETTERS

    public String getNome ()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public String getClasse ()
    {
        return this.classe;
    }

    public int getDefesa ()
    {
        return this.defesa;
    }

    public int getCritico ()
    {
        return this.critico; 
    }

    public int getHealthPoints ()
    {
        return this.healthPoints;
    }

    public int getManaPoints ()
    {
        return this.manaPoints; 
    }

    public int getDanoMinimo ()
    {
        return this.danoMinimo;
    }

    public int getDanoMaximo ()
    {
        return this.danoMaximo;
    }

    public void Ataque (Personagem inimigo)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int ataque; 

        ataque = rand.nextInt(this.danoMaximo) + this.danoMinimo; 
        inimigo.healthPoints = inimigo.healthPoints - (ataque - inimigo.defesa); 

    }

    public void recebeDano (Personagem inimigo ,int ataque)
    {
        this.healthPoints = ataque - defesa;

    }

}
```

> Classe Principal

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random; 

class Partida 
{
    static Scanner scanf = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random  rand  = new Random();

    static Personagem jogador = new Personagem(); 
    static Personagem inimigo = new Personagem(); 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Introducao();
        telaPersonagem();
        chamaTurno();
        jogadorTurno();
        cpuTurno();
        vitoria();

    }

    public static void Introducao ()
    {
        System.out.println("SEJA BEM-VINDO A ARENA, GUERREIRO! DIGA-NOS SEU NOME: "); 
        jogador.setNome("LUCAS"); 
        inimigo.setNome("LUCAS"); 

    }

    public static void telaPersonagem() // MOSTRA A TELA COM INFORMAÇÕES DOS PERSONAGENS 
    {
        System.out.println("NOME: " + jogador.getNome() + "                     NOME:" + inimigo.getNome());
        System.out.println("HP: " + jogador.getHealthPoints() + "                                   HP: "  + inimigo.getHealthPoints());
        System.out.println("MP: " + jogador.getManaPoints() + "                             MP: "  + inimigo.getManaPoints());

    }

    public static void chamaTurno() 
    {

        int jogadorAgi; 
        int cpuAgi; 

        do
        {

        jogadorAgi = rand.nextInt(1) + jogador.getAgilidade(); 
        cpuAgi = rand.nextInt(1) + inimigo.getAgilidade(); 

            if(jogadorAgi > cpuAgi)
            {
                jogadorTurno(); 

            } else
            {


            }

        } while(jogadorAgi != cpuAgi);

    }

    public static void jogadorTurno()
    {
        int acao; 

        do
        {

            System.out.println("SEU TURNO"); 
            System.out.println(""); 
            System.out.println("Escolha uma acao"); 
            System.out.println("1 - Atacar"); 
            System.out.println("2 - Atacar forte"); 
            System.out.println("3 - Atacar FORTE MESMO"); 
            acao = scanf.nextInt(); 

            switch(acao)
            {
                case 1 : 
                    jogador.Ataque(inimigo);
                    System.out.println("Ataque realizado com sucesso"); 
                    telaPersonagem();
                    chamaTurno(); 
                    break; 

                default : 
                    System.out.println("Digite um comando valido"); 
            }   

        } while(jogador.healthPoints != 0 || jogador.healthPoints < 0); 

    }

    public static void cpuTurno()
    {
        int acao; 

        acao = rand.nextInt(1) + 3;

        System.out.println("TURNO INIMIGO"); 

        do
        {
            switch (acao)
            {
                case 1:
                    inimigo.Ataque(jogador); 
                    System.out.println("Você e atacado com sucesso"); 
                    chamaTurno();
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    inimigo.Ataque(jogador); 
                    System.out.println("Você e atacado com sucesso"); 
                    chamaTurno(); 
                    break;

                case 3:
                    inimigo.Ataque(jogador); 
                    System.out.println("Você e atacado com sucesso");  
                    break;
            }
        } while(inimigo.healthPoints != 0 || inimigo.healthPoints <= 0);

    }

    public static void vitoria()
    {
        if(jogador.healthPoints == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Voce perdeu!");
        }

        if(inimigo.healthPoints == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Voce venceu!");
        }
    }

}
```

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Por favor, apresente um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o codigo,

Comment: Ops! Perdão, não quis colocar o código todo por achar ele muito grande, desculpe-me. Aqui estão as três classes do código.

Comment: Faça com que seus métodos recebam como parâmetro tanto um herói quanto um vilão, coloque-os dentro do `main` e remova o `static` dos atributos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema da sua solução é que os atributos da sua classe Personagem são static. Atributos static são atributos da classe e não atributos dos objetos.

Remova o static que irá funcionar.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!